# Is it allowed to write $\binom{n}{n+1}$ = 0?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

For ex. $\binom{n}{n}$ = $\binom{n-1}{n-1}$ + $\binom{n-1}{n}$ according to the rule $\binom{n}{i}$ = $\binom{n-1}{i-1}$ + $\binom{n-1}{i}$

Comment: That is done by convention.

Comment: Ok this is helpful for induction proofs

Comment: Yes, it is. You can also go for $\binom{n}{k}$ defined for $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ and $k\in\mathbb Z$ where $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k\notin\{0,\dots,n\}$. It is advisable though to mention it if you use that convention.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it's not an arbitrary "convention". By definition,
$$\binom x{n+1}=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)}{(n+1)!},$$
a polynomial of degree $n+1$ with zeros at $x=0,1,2,\dots,n$.

Answer (score 0):

Defining $\binom{n}{k}$ as the number of size-$k$ subsets of a size-$n$ set, your statement is indeed correct. You can even keep the usual formula in terms of factorials, viz. $\frac{1}{(-1)!}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0$.